# Java Cryptography throwing Exception while initializing Cipher: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a simple test "sometext" using **"AES/GCM/NoPadding"**.
I have a main method in which I am first passing a string as an argument that is supposed to get encrypted. The encrypted text will appear on the console. Then following that decryption gets called (by passing the encrypted text) to check if the decryption is working fine, i.e. if I am getting back the same text after decryption. 
I am calling the main class, and its failing in my `getCipher()` custom method with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" my.package.EncryptionException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
        at my.package.Encryptor.encrypt(Encryptor.java:76)
        at my.package.Encryptor.encrypt(Encryptor.java:61)
        at my.package.Encryptor.main(Encryptor.java:151)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
        at my.package.Encryptor.getCipher(Encryptor.java:134)
        at my.package.Encryptor.encrypt(Encryptor.java:69)
        ... 2 more
```

I am not sure why is this Illegal key size giving error. I have my key **"SecREtKeY"** within 16 chars.
Here is the code below:

```
public class Encryptor {

    private static final String ALGORITHM_AES256 = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    private static final int IV_LEN = 16;
    private static final int KEY_LEN = 32;
    private final SecureRandom random;
    private final byte[] inputKey;
    private final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    private final Cipher cipher;

    Encryptor() throws EncryptionException 
    {
        String secretKey = "SecREtKeY";
        byte[] key = secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        if (key == null) {
            throw new EncryptionException("Null Key");
        }

        inputKey = new byte[key.length];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, inputKey, 0, inputKey.length);

        byte[] aesKey = trimKey(key);
        System.out.println("aesKey.length: "+aesKey.length);

        try
        {
            random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            this.secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_AES256);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new EncryptionException(e);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Encrypts plaint text. Returns Encrypted String.
     */
    String encrypt(String plaintext) throws EncryptionException
    {
        return encrypt(plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    String encrypt(byte[] plaintext) throws EncryptionException
    {
        try 
        {
            byte[] iv = getRandom(IV_LEN);
            Cipher msgcipher = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, iv);
            byte[] encryptedTextBytes = msgcipher.doFinal(plaintext);
            byte[] payload = concat(iv, encryptedTextBytes);

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(payload);
        } 
        catch (BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e){
            throw new EncryptionException(e);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Decrypts plaint text. Returns decrypted String.
     */
    String decrypt(String ciphertext) throws EncryptionException 
    {
        return decrypt(Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext));
    }

    String decrypt(byte[] cipherBytes) throws EncryptionException 
    {
        byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOf(cipherBytes, IV_LEN);

        byte[] cipherText = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherBytes, IV_LEN, cipherBytes.length);
        try {
            Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, iv);
            byte[] decrypt = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
            return new String(decrypt, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new EncryptionException(e);
        }
    }


    private byte[] trimKey(byte[] key)
    {
        byte[] outkey = new byte[KEY_LEN];

        if(key.length >= KEY_LEN) {
            System.arraycopy(key, key.length - KEY_LEN, outkey, 0, KEY_LEN);
        } 
        else {
            System.arraycopy(key, 0, outkey, 0, key.length);
        }

        return outkey;
    }

    private byte[] getRandom(int size) 
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        random.nextBytes(data);
        return data;
    }

    private byte[] concat(byte[] first, byte[] second) 
    {
        byte[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }

    private Cipher getCipher(int encryptMode, byte[] iv) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException 
    {
        GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(IV_LEN * 8, iv);
        cipher.init(encryptMode, getSecretKeySpec(), gcmSpec);
        return cipher;
    }

    private SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec() {
        return secretKeySpec;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        if(args.length == 1) {
            String plainText = args[0];

            Encryptor aes = new Encryptor();

            String encryptedString = aes.encrypt(plainText);
            System.out.println(plainText + ":" + encryptedString);

            String decryptedString = aes.decrypt(encryptedString);
            System.out.println(encryptedString+":"+decryptedString);
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("USAGE: java my.package.Encryptor [text to encrypt]");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why am i getting this error ?

Comment: Note the key size is 16-bytes `secretKey = "SecREtKeY"` but specified as `KEY_LEN = 32`: they don't match. Also see the answer by @Jens and note that 128-bit AES is essentially as secure as 256-bit, neither can be brute forced unless the key is weak and then both have the same vulnerability.

Comment: so should I make `KEY_LEN = 16` ?

Comment: You should make `KEY_LEN` the same as the size of the actual key. With a key size of 16-bytes there is no need to install the `Java Cryptography Extension`.

Comment: I made the `KEY_LEN = secretKey.length();`. But now I am getting the exception `Invalid AES key length: 9 bytes  Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 9 bytes
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(AESCipher.java:509)`

Comment: Use a debugger! Your `trimKey()` function isn't returning a properly sized key, it's just copying the key you pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size` indicates that you have not installed the JCE (Java Cryptography Extension). It is needed for AES256

For Java 8 you can download it here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: Thanks alot @Jens...that was the problem :D. Thanks a tons :D :D